# Change supported Version of an released iOS, iPadOS & macOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, version

I released `iOS` / `iPadOS` / `macOS` app on the AppStore, which has a minimum Version of `iOS 13` / `iPadOS 13` / `macOS 10`.

I would like to use the new features introduced in newer versions and am not sure, whether it is possible to change the min. supported version with an app update.

**Question:** Would it be possible to change the `min. supported version` with a new update and release it to the AppStore? Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the minimum supported version. The better question is if you should. You may exclude some users from new versions of your app if you do. This article explores this question and some of the factors involved in making the decision.

https://www.avanderlee.com/workflow/minimum-ios-version/